# Can I automatically reboot if disconnected from the internet?

Tags: ubuntu, script, reboot

I have an old desktop that I'm running as a web server from my home while I'm at college.  The internet at home is crappy and a lot of times when it goes down, the desktop can't reconnect without a reboot.

Is there a way to make a script that loads on startup and every 12 hours or so, will attempt to ping the router, and if it fails, reboots the server?

EDIT:
Ok, I was able to make this script after googling around a bit.

```
#!/bin/bash

ping -c 1 192.168.1.1 > /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  reboot
fi
```

That tests if the ping is successful, and if it's not it reboots.
Now what do I need to do to make this run on a set schedule?

Comment: If you're having to reboot the server, and not the router - the problem isn't with your Internet connection that you like so much.  You've got other problems that need to be addressed on your desktop / server - and additional scripting likely isn't going to help.

Comment: Ya I know there are other problems that need to be addressed, but I'm leaving in under 24 hours and I need a quick fix that will work until I come back home.  I know it's not a perfect solution, but at least so far rebooting it has been working.
And anyways, the server is pretty much only being used for personal testing use so a crappy little fix like this is fine for now.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu server 11.10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't mention the operating system, but if you're using Windows, something like this may be helpful:  [JScript for Ping, Renew IP and Network Info / Repair](http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2009/06/jscript-ping-renew-ip-network.html).

This is a script I put together for a similar issue.  It does pretty much exactly what you're looking for, in that it pings the default gateway (which will be your router) on a given schedule, and then takes required action if the ping fails.

In this case, the problem PCs didn't need to be rebooted, but simply have an `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` scripted in order to regain connectivity.  Something like this might work well for your case as well.  If a full reboot is still required, this script could be easily modified to account for that as well.

For Linux, you could use a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

ping -c5 192.168.1.1

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "ok"
else
    reboot
fi
```

This works because of the return code of `ping`, as detailed in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping):

> If ping does not receive any reply packets at all it will exit with
>   code 1. If a packet count and deadline are both specified, and fewer
>   than count packets are received by the time the deadline has arrived,
>   it  will  also exit with code 1.  On other error it exits with code 2.
>   Otherwise it exits with code 0. This makes it possible to use the exit
>   code to see if a host is alive or not.

After replacing `192.168.1.1` with the address of your router, you could schedule this to run every hour or so using cron.  In order to reboot, you'll need to run this as `root`.  For default Ubuntu, you can add a cron job using:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

To have this check run every hour, for example:

```
00 * * * * /path/to/script/pingRouterCheckReboot.sh
```

You'll need to ensure that the script is executable (`chmod +x`).

If you find that bringing the interface down and back up is sufficient, you could do this instead, doing something like `ifdown eth0; ifup eth0`.  Or, combine approaches:  First do this, and then do the ping test again.  If connectivity still isn't restored, then force the drastic measure of a full reboot.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm running ubuntu server.  Although ya, I might be able to do a similar release and renew if it's down.

Comment: @user1056869 - Please see my updates in the answer for a Linux / Ubuntu solution as well.

Comment: Oh thanks, that should perfectly.  I'll try that out.